# Show that $P(A\cap B) =\frac14$

Tags: probability

A ball is drawn at random from $4$ balls labelled $1, 2, 3, 4$. The sample space is $Ω = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$
and we take $P(\{i\}) = \frac14$
for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$. and we consider the events $A = \{1\} ∪ \{2\},\  B = \{1\} ∪ \{3\}, \ C = \{1\} ∪ \{4\}$.

Show that $P(A\cap B) =\dfrac14$

**Attempt:**

$A∩B = (\{1\} ∪ \{2\}) ∩ (\{1\} ∪ \{3\})$

$= \{1\} ∪ (\{2\} ∩ \{3\})$ by the distributive law

$P(A∩B) = P(\{1\} ∪ (\{2\} ∩ \{3\}))$

$= \dfrac 14 + \left(\dfrac 14 \times \dfrac 14\right) = \dfrac 14 + \dfrac 1{16} = \dfrac5{16}$

Am I doing something wrong here? When I don't simplify using the distributive law, I get the correct answer of $\frac 14$, like so:

$$P(A∩B) = (\{1\} ∪ \{2\}) ∩ (\{1\} ∪ \{3\}) = \left(\dfrac 14+\dfrac 14\right) \times \left(\dfrac 14+\dfrac 14\right) = \frac 12 \times \frac12 = \dfrac 14$$

Comment: Hint:  $(\{2\} \cap \{3\} = \emptyset$ and so $P(A\cap B) = P(\{1\}) + P(\emptyset) = \frac 14$.  Also, $P(C\cap D)$ equals $P(C)\times P(D)$ only when $C$ and $D$ are _independent_ events. Using this formula indiscriminately as you have done in _two_ different places is a habit that you should learn to break as soon as possible. That _last_ $\frac 14$ that you found is the correct _numerical_ value of $P(A\cap B)$ but the derivation is all wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\{2\}\cap\{3\} = \varnothing$, so in your calculations

$$P(A \cap B) = P(\{1\} \cup (\{2\} \cap \{3\})) = P(\{1\}) + P(\{2\} \cap \{3\}) = \frac14 + 0 = \frac14$$

You incorrectly evaluated $P(\{2\} \cap \{3\})$ as $\dfrac{1}{16}$, which is the difference of the two numerical answers in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$A∩B = (\{1\} ∪ \{2\}) ∩ (\{1\} ∪ \{3\})= \{1\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)=\frac24+\frac24-\frac34=\frac14.$$